# R code: Extracting highly correlated variables and Running multivariate regression model with selected variables

Tags: r, regression

I have a huge data which has about 2,000 variables and about 10,000 observations.
Initially, I wanted to run a regression model for each one with 1999 independent variables and then do stepwise model selection.
Therefore, I would have 2,000 models.

However, unfortunately R presented errors because of lack of memory..
So, alternatively, I have tried to remove some independent variables which are low correlation value- maybe lower than .5-

With variables which are highly correlated with each dependent variable, I would like to run regression model..

I tried to do follow codes, even `melt` function doesn't work because of memory issue.. oh god..

```
test<-data.frame(X1=rnorm(50,mean=50,sd=10),
             X2=rnorm(50,mean=5,sd=1.5),
             X3=rnorm(50,mean=200,sd=25))

test$X1[10]<-5

test$X2[10]<-5
test$X3[10]<-530

corr<-cor(test)
diag(corr)<-NA
corr[upper.tri(corr)]<-NA
melt(corr) 
#it doesn't work with my own data..because of lack of memory.
```

Please help me.. and thank you so much in advance..!

Comment: consider looking into the `glmnet` package as a more principled, and more efficient, way of handling this problem ...

Comment: thank you for kind comments! I just quickly take a look at it. but I could not clearly understand what is "lasso or elastic-net regulariza-
tion path" mean..

Comment: see chapter 3 of http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/ (not necessarily an easy read but well worth the investment if you're going to work in this area ...)

Comment: I don't think the goals are expressed coherently. The distinction between dependent and independent variables appears fuzzy.

Comment: Dwin, yes all 2000 variables could be dependent variable itself for one model and could be one of the independent variables for other 1999 models. I understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation if might be worth trying sparsity inducing techniques such as the Lasso. Here a sparse subset of variables is selected by constraining the sum of absolute values of the regression coefficients.

This will give you a reduced subset of variables which are the most relevant (and due to the nature of the Lasso algorithm also the most correlated, which was what you were looking for)

In R you can use the LARS package and information about the Lasso can be found here:
http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html

Also a very good resource is: http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/